# How to scrape Medium profiles?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape profiles from Medium.

I even prepared the script. It's working too:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://medium.com/@daranept27')
r.html.render()

x = r.html.find('a.eg.bv')
[print(elem.text) for elem in x]
```

But the thing is that it's working with only one profile link, i.e **if you change the username, the whole code changes! The class changes, CSS selector changes, XPATH changes, everything changes!**

I can scrape through XML too but what if I have to scrape by myself?

Is there no way? Because nothing seems common between them. I need a method, an idea :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://maxufberg.medium.com/')

r.html.render()

divs = r.html.find('div')

lst = []

for div in divs:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(div.html,'html5lib')
    div_tag = soup.find()
    try:
        title = div_tag.section.div.h1.a.text
        if title not in lst: lst.append(title)
    except:
        pass

print("\n".join(lst))
```

Output:

```
Every Election Day Question You Actually Care About, Answered
That PA Voter Everyone Is Obsessed With Was My High School Spanish Teacher
A Biden Supporter Has It Out With Her Trump-Supporting Father
She Supports Trump. Her Daughter Supports Biden. We Helped Them Hash It Out.
This Week in Trumpland Corruption: The President’s Personal Piggy Bank
This Week in Trumpland Corruption: The Taxes Return
Beyond Abortion: What’s at Stake With a Right-Wing Court
The Coronavirus Is Tearing Through Native Communities
This Week in Trumpland Corruption: Dying for a Vaccine
```

Output for this link - https://susanorlean.medium.com/:

```
The Last Minute Dread You’re Feeling Right About Now
Another Essential Writing Tool You Should Own in Large Quantities
When You Want What You Can’t Have
How to Know a Story Idea When You See One
The World Economy, the Pandemic, Dogs, and Me
Nothing Sweeter Than The Sound of Your Own Name, Even When It’s Wrong
All the Tools You Will Ever Need To Become a Writer
How to Dress for Work When You Never Leave Home
The Glory and Heartbreak of the Old Dog
The Friday Drink You Didn’t Know You Needed
The (Unexpected) Pleasures of Parenting During the Pandemic
Making Yogurt Magic
```

Output for this link - https://medium.com/@daranept27:

```
Seven Days -Between Life And Death
Have you ever encountered a fake friend? If So, Try These Simple Tips To Overcome it.
Does Anybody Ever Wonder Why He’s My Everything?
Ladies, Why Should You Treat Your Face Like The Coloring Books?
Listen, Girl, Aren’t You Curious How The Last Line Could Be This Hurtful?
The girl name “Rich”
She Lost Her Beloved Mother, But Why She Asserted that Loss Was Not Just A Loss sometimes?
You Used To Try This Lonely. Have You Ever Imagine The flavor You Tried To Eat it with Your Lover?
If You Have Siblings, You Won’t Comprehend this. Have You Ever Wonder How A Child Feels Like? This Is How It Perceives.
Is It Okay To Help A Stranger?
The Nightmare Was Always Considered A Bad Omen, But It Turned Incredible Differently.
If You’re A Woman Or Girl Who Loves To Wear Lipstick, Read This Poetry.
She Wants To Spread This Poetry For Every Girl Or Woman That Was Born Just Like The Way She Was.
```

Comment: Didn't tried it yet, I think it will, but don't worry as I did it before. I click on accepted always :)

Comment: But heyy, can you explain me this line? `title = div_tag.section.div.h1.a.text` and 
`if title not in lst: lst.append(title)`

Comment: `title = div_tag.section.div.h1.a.text` This is the path from the `div` element to the text. `if title not in lst: lst.append(title)` appends `title` to the `list` if `title` is not in `list`. If the `if` is removed, then many duplicates would be printed.

Comment: Heyy, umm do you know the answer to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64690280/requests-html-error-while-running-on-flask?noredirect=1#comment114385235_64690280 Seems like `flask` and `requests_html` is not supported to work with each other...

Comment: Sry but I don't think I can help u. Cuz I haven't worked with `flask`.

Comment: Yup ok, no problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the parts of the profile you want. Get some of them and **try to identify a pattern** of sorts.

I've looked into

https://medium.com/@daranept27

https://maxufberg.medium.com/

https://susanorlean.medium.com/

For instance some "articles" have a `<section>` tag where the content lies.
The class seems to change but the tag remains. Try to filter by that. Then you have an `<h1>` and then an `<h2>`. After this follows the `<figure>` that contains the image and then the content.

When the code changes a lot i usualy focus on structure than focusing too much on classes or css.