# Requests-html: error while running on flask

Tags: python, flask, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests-html

I've prepared a script that was using `requests-html` which was working fine.

I deployed it in the flask app and now it's giving me `RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-3'.`

**Here's the full error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\intel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
 .
 .
 .
  File "C:\Users\intel\Desktop\One page\main.py", line 18, in hello_world
    r.html.render()
  File "C:\Users\intel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\requests_html.py", line 586, in render
    self.browser = self.session.browser  # Automatically create a event loop and browser
  File "C:\Users\intel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\requests_html.py", line 727, in browser
    self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  File "C:\Users\intel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\asyncio\events.py", line 639, in get_event_loop

    raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-3'.
```

**Here's the original code:**

```
from flask import Flask
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/<user>')
def hello_world(user):
    session = HTMLSession()
    r = session.get('https://medium.com/@' + str(user))

    print(r)

    r.html.render()

    divs = r.html.find('div')

    lst = []

    for div in divs:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(div.html, 'html5lib')
        div_tag = soup.find()
        try:
            title = div_tag.section.div.h1.a['href']
            if title not in lst:
                lst.append(title)
        except:
            pass

    return "\n".join(lst)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: I don't think flask and request-html work well together. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53180586/8573336).

Answer (score 0):

You should use Quart library built on top of flask. That will solve your problem.

**Installation**: `pip install quart`

```py
from quart import Quart
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession
app  = Quart(__name__)
@app.route('/<user>')
def hello_world(user):
    session = AsyncHTMLSession()
    r = await session.get('https://medium.com/@' + str(user))

    print(r)

    await r.html.arender()

    divs = r.html.find('div')

    lst = []

    for div in divs:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(div.html, 'html5lib')
        div_tag = soup.find()
        try:
            title = div_tag.section.div.h1.a['href']
            if title not in lst:
                lst.append(title)
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: are you saying don't use flask at this point? like when someone ask about laravel, just use rails smh

Comment: so many things wrong with your code. await only allowed within await function! mention the bs4 library! please test your code before answering

Comment: I just suggested using Quart instead of flask because flask doesn't support Async/Await paradigm. You can edit it and make it an async function.

Comment: You can also use FastAPI instead of Quart, FastAPI is a powerful library. I just suggested the way to use async/await in python(Flask)